# query-exporter in Docker container not working

Tags: python, docker, sqlite, docker-compose, prometheus

I am trying to get [query-exporter](https://github.com/albertodonato/query-exporter) to run in a Docker container. With advice from the developer I have enabled IPv6 in docker by putting:

```
{
  "experimental": true,
  "ip6tables": true
}
```

in my docker daemon.json and restarted.

I am using the following docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  prometheus:
    container_name: prometheus
    image: prom/prometheus
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus/
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles'
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    networks:
      - prom_app_net
    

  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana
    user: '472'
    restart: always
    environment:
      GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS: 'grafana-clock-panel,grafana-simple-json-datasource'
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./grafana/provisioning/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/
      - './grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini'
    env_file:
      - ./grafana/.env_grafana
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
    networks:
      - prom_app_net


  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.10
    hostname: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: slurm_acct_db
      MYSQL_USER: slurm
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - var_lib_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - slurm
#    network_mode: host


  slurmdbd:
    image: prom-slurm-cluster:${IMAGE_TAG:-21.08.6}
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        SLURM_TAG: ${SLURM_TAG:-slurm-21-08-6-1}
    command: ["slurmdbd"]
    container_name: slurmdbd
    hostname: slurmdbd
    volumes:
      - etc_munge:/etc/munge
      - etc_slurm:/etc/slurm
      - var_log_slurm:/var/log/slurm
      - cgroups:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    expose:
      - "6819"
    ports:
      - "6819:6819"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    privileged: true
    cgroup: host
    networks:
      - slurm
    #network_mode: host

  slurmctld:
    image: prom-slurm-cluster:${IMAGE_TAG:-21.08.6}
    command: ["slurmctld"] 
    container_name: slurmctld
    hostname: slurmctld
    volumes:
      - etc_munge:/etc/munge
      - etc_slurm:/etc/slurm
      - slurm_jobdir:/data
      - var_log_slurm:/var/log/slurm
      - etc_prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw
    expose:
      - "6817"
      - "8080"
      - "8081"
      - "8082/tcp"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8081:8081
      - 8082:8082/tcp
    depends_on:
      - "slurmdbd"
    privileged: true
    cgroup: host

    #network_mode: host
    networks:
      - slurm

  c1:
    image: prom-slurm-cluster:${IMAGE_TAG:-21.08.6}
    command: ["slurmd"]
    hostname: c1
    container_name: c1
    volumes:
      - etc_munge:/etc/munge
      - etc_slurm:/etc/slurm
      - slurm_jobdir:/data
      - var_log_slurm:/var/log/slurm
      - cgroups:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    expose:
      - "6818"
    depends_on:
      - "slurmctld"
    privileged: true
    cgroup: host 
    #network_mode: host
    networks:
      - slurm
    

  c2:
    image: prom-slurm-cluster:${IMAGE_TAG:-21.08.6}
    command: ["slurmd"]
    hostname: c2
    container_name: c2
    volumes:
      - etc_munge:/etc/munge
      - etc_slurm:/etc/slurm
      - slurm_jobdir:/data
      - var_log_slurm:/var/log/slurm
      - cgroups:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    expose:
      - "6818"
      - "22"
    depends_on:
      - "slurmctld"
    privileged: true
    cgroup: host
    networks:
      - slurm
    #network_mode: host




volumes:
  etc_munge:
  etc_slurm:
  slurm_jobdir:
  var_lib_mysql:
  var_log_slurm:
  grafana_data:
  prometheus_data:
  cgroups: 
  etc_prometheus:

networks:
  prom_app_net:
  slurm:
    enable_ipv6: true
    ipam:
      config: 
        - subnet: 2001:0DB8::/112
```

Then installed query-exporter on the slurmctld container and run it with the following config.yaml:

```
databases:
  db1:
    dsn: sqlite:////test.db
    connect-sql:
      - PRAGMA application_id = 123
      - PRAGMA auto_vacuum = 1
    labels:
      region: us1
      app: app1


metrics:
  metric1:
    type: gauge
    description: A sample gauge


queries:
  query1:
    interval: 5
    databases: [db1]
    metrics: [metric1]
    sql: SELECT random() / 1000000000000000 AS metric1
```

But it is not working - prometheus lists the target as being down:

[image: prometheus window down]

But the container set-up seems to be fine as if I run the following test exporter:

```
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Summary
import random
import time

# Create a metric to track time spent and requests made.
REQUEST_TIME = Summary('request_processing_seconds', 'Time spent processing request')

# Decorate function with metric.
@REQUEST_TIME.time()
def process_request(t):
    """A dummy function that takes some time."""
    time.sleep(t)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start up the server to expose the metrics.
    start_http_server(8082)
    # Generate some requests.
    while True:
        process_request(random.random())
```

Prometheus can connect to the target fine:

[image: target up]

Can anyone see what the problem could be?

Thanks!

**Update**

I run query-exporter by hand on the slurmctld container. There isnt anything in the container logs about query-exporter:

```
2023-07-10 10:11:37 ---> Starting the MUNGE Authentication service (munged) ...
2023-07-10 10:11:37 ---> Waiting for slurmdbd to become active before starting slurmctld ...
2023-07-10 10:11:37 -- slurmdbd is not available.  Sleeping ...
2023-07-10 10:11:39 -- slurmdbd is now active ...
2023-07-10 10:11:39 ---> starting systemd ...
```

I think th etest_query.py that works is using IPv4 on port 8082, while the query exporter is trying to bind IPv6.

`docker port slurmctld` gives:

```
8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8080
8080/tcp -> [::]:8080
8081/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8081
8081/tcp -> [::]:8081
8082/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8082
8082/tcp -> [::]:8082
```

I guess i need to pint prometheus at `8082/tcp -> [::]:8082` when the query-exporter runs, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: can you show the container logs of the exporter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running with `query-exporter config.yaml -H 0.0.0.0 -p 8082` gets it to work.